# SCSS/SASS strange behavior with ampersand

Tags: sass

I am trying to use the Ampersand after a parent while using SASS so that I can modify behavior of an element when the parent's class changes.

My scss looks like this:

```
#filter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    @extend .bg-color--blue;
    @extend .animate;

    &.open {
        transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .filter {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        &__container {
            display:none;
        }

        &__pull {
            width:65px;
            height:50px;
            @extend .bg-color--blue;
            @extend .animate;

            #filter.open & {
                @extend .bg-color--blue-dark;
                color:red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main line I'm looking at is at the end of the hierarchy. `#filter.open & {`

It's currently outputting this:

```
#filter.open #filter .filter__pull {
    color: red; 
}
```

What I need it to output is this:

```
#filter.open .filter__pull {
    color: red;
}
```

I'm not sure why it's adding that extra `#filter` in there.  On other projects I use this on, this doesn't happen.

any ideas?

Comment: Try changing `#filter.open & {` to `&#filter.open {`

Comment: @developernator, That would make it `#filter .filter__pull#filter.open` which isn't correct either

Comment: it seems that the & goes all the way to the root of where you started...

Comment: What about trying out `@at-root `

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but it seems that the Ampersand (&) at the end of the line will copy everything all the way up to the root of your nested SCSS.

I've since removed the class `.filter` out from under the id `#filter` (confusing, I know) and made the `.filter` the base element in the file.

This way, when the `&` copies the hierarchy, it does not copy all the way up to the `#filter` element

```
#filter {
  ...

  &.open {
    ...
  }
}
.filter {
  ...

  &__container {
    ...
  }

  &__pull {
    ...

    #filter.open &  {
      @extend .bg-color--blue-dark;

      i {
        transform: translate3d(-100%, -50%, 0);
        @extend .animate;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#filter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    @extend .bg-color--blue;
    @extend .animate;

    &.open {
        transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .filter {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        &__container {
            display:none;
        }

        &__pull {
            width:65px;
            height:50px;
            @extend .bg-color--blue;
            @extend .animate;

            @at-root {
                @extend .bg-color--blue-dark;
                color:red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would `@at-root` make this look at the root, `#filter` again

Answer (score 0):

At this stage I think you are trying too hard to cut down on the amount of SCSS you're writing, rather than actually making it more *readable* and *manageable*. Why not do this:

```
#filter {
    ...

    &.open {
        transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        .filter {
            &__pull {
                @extend .bg-color--blue-dark;
                color:red;
            }
        }
    }

    .filter {
        ...

        &__pull {
            width:65px;
            height:50px;
            @extend .bg-color--blue;
            @extend .animate;
        }
    }
}
```

This is much more readable and you are grouping all of your `open` css into its own block, so if you ever want to change the value of the class `open`, eg. to `active` or something, you change it in one place.